# Do you retain the benefits of Vampirism after it has been lifted?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, curses

You somehow managed to get cured of vampirism (for example). You maybe really happy to not have to consume blood ever again, but do you keep what you have gained from it:

I) Bonus to your characteristics?

II) Bonus to your skills?

III) Bonus Feats?

Comment: If you want to know about curses as well, I suggest making it a separate question. I chose to edit this to speak about vampirism (no curses) since your other question makes it clear this is the problem your group is facing right now. Of course you can also roll back my edit and ask about curses here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No more being a vampire means being a vampire no more.
As soon as you find a way to get rid of vampirism, you lose both the benefits and the drawbacks.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, as mxyzplk stated, vampirism is not a curse, so my example was wrong.

Comment: @Nyakouai I noticed the disconnection between the so called "curse of vampirism" you might be used to thanks to narrative and the mechanical tag "curse" and I considered the former. As you might have noticed, I never once called it a curse in my answer, which still stands.

Comment: +1 for the list of benefits and drawbacks being consequences of being a vampire, rather than independent and unrelated changes that together get called "vampirism."

Answer (score -1):

You should not be able to have your cake and eat it too.

If you lose the drawbacks of a curse then you should lose the benefits as well unless there is some other drawback (i.e. spending a feat) that takes its place for balance purposes.